# Nginx как компьютеру отдать index.html а телефону отдать mobile.html?

Tags: nginx, redirect, mobile, rewrite, mobile-web

```
location / {

    if ($http_user_agent ~* "android") {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /mobile.html =404;
      break;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

что я делаю не так? (понятно что регулярку я сделал условной)

Comment: Только реврайт недопустим, так как реврайт редирект делает и ссылка поменяется, а надо чтобы ссылка осталась site.com/ только файл отдался не index.html а mobile.html

Answer (score 1):

тогда так:
создаем переменную выше раздела server

```
map $http_user_agent $index {
    default           index.html;
    "~*android"       mobile.html;
}
```

возможно index.html и mobile.html в кавычки надо заключить, - если тест не пройдет.
вставляем переменную в try_files

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$index =404;
}
```

Comment: Лучший вариант, так как конструкции `if` вообще лучше не использовать.

Comment: ух тыы, хитро! шикарно! щас попробуем! спасибо мужик что не забиваешь на меня и помогаешь. я тут уже надежду потерял

Comment: Почему то если url равен / то отдает index.html а если url равен /blablabla то отдает mobile.html

Comment: может быть в коде есть еще location у которого приоритет выше?

Answer (score 0):

есть еще такой вариант,

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (iphone|аndroid|blackberry)){
    rewrite ^/(.*)index.html$ $1mobile.html permanent;
}
```

это надо выше location поставить. предварительно нужно проверить через nginx -t, чтоб не было ошибок в файле конфигурации.

Comment: Да, но это реврайт, а значит ссылка поменяется. А надо чтобы адрес был site.com/ но просто за место index.html отдавалась mobile.html

Comment: а хотя да, 301 еще закэшируется и начнет всегда мобильную версию отдавать

Comment: Блин, прикинь, гуглю гуглю, походу ни как этого не сделать без реврайта о_О че то не верится. дичь какая-то. Неужели самый быстрый и лучший сервер в мире не способен на такую мелочь?

Comment: а ну так все верно, надо без permanent.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (iphone|аndroid|blackberry)){
    rewrite ^/(.*)index.html$ $1mobile.html redirect;
}
```

Если адрес меняется - это в любом случае redirect. Без него не может быть.

Comment: адрес сайта тот же останется, только index.html поменяется на mobile.html. но пользователь не пишет index.html он в корень обычно заходит, значит там выше еще redirect где-то прописан из корня на index.html

Comment: а не, до меня не дошло сразу. если заходим на site.ru то адрес должен тот же оставаться, только подсовываться в ответ либо modile, либо индекс, это через try_files и делается. а что nginx - не пишет ошибки?

Comment: nginx пишет что try_filies недопустимо использовать внутри if. мол они как бы альтернативы друг другу. мол либо иф  либо трай файлс. но трай файлсом не прочитать юзер агент ни как.